# Warning: expects resource but string given

Tags: php

I get:

> "Resource id #8
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given"

Heres the code:

```
$sql="SELECT password FROM user WHERE userid=$userid";    
echo $password=mysql_query($sql);
        
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($password)) {
    $password = $row['password'];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to use a while loop if there is (at most) only one user with the given `userid`

Comment: May be you better try to *understand* what is happened, than just "reuse it for something else"? It won't work anywhere, if "reused" exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `$password` in the loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($password)) {  <-------- $password as resource
    $password = $row['password'];             <-------- $password as string
}
```

this should work:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($password)) {
    $password_record = $row['password'];
}
```

Comment: Doh - Thanks.

Strange as I reused that code for something else and it didn't complain. :-)

Comment: @Damien that loop probably had only one record :)